# Firebase Duplicates New Uploads On Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Whenever I make a continuous upload to Firebase, the latest photo that I upload will replace all the other link. it's a weird error and hard to believe.

**get result image**

```
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image2.jpg";
        selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        ImageCompression imageCompression = new ImageCompression(this);
        String oath = imageCompression.compressImage(filePath);
        uriN = Uri.fromFile(new File(oath));
```

**upload the image**

```
private void fabSend(){
    if (uriN!=null){
        final StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + ".jpg");
        photoRef.putFile(uriN).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                image = (downloadUrl.toString());
                postRef.push().setValue(new myAdapter(image,
                description ,
                user.getDisplayName())).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                              progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                              uriN = null;
                              fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                       });
                    }
              });}
```

The fact is if I quit the activity and relaunch it again, this does not happen. I have tried using [reCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) but the same happens.

All links are different `ie different upload tokens and different images`
but the last picture that is uploaded is the one shown for all links.

Comment: What is `postRef` and why does it need to have the last value from `UploadTask`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov postref is the database reference to post the posts made after the image is uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're stating that all images must have the same name (image2.jpg) in this line:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image2.jpg";
```

What you should do instead is get the `Uri` from the `data` parameter in `onActivityResult()` (I assume that's were you're getting the image result:

```
        selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        ImageCompression imageCompression = new ImageCompression(this);
        String oath = imageCompression.compressImage(filePath);
        uriN = Uri.fromFile(new File(oath));
```

**Edit:** You can change the name before sending it to Firebase Storage, maybe adding date and time. Like this:

```
String newName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm").format(new Date());
final StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child("IMG-"+newName+ ".jpg");
```

Comment: getting the image uri is done offline and must be made through the file path as file is saved in the directory before on activity result it is then compressed and the result is stored in the new uri and posted on the imageview too which confirms that the new image is correctly transformed.

Comment: You have a point. It's better to delete the old file before creating a new one to avoid using too much of the resources. I have fixed my issue though with your logic